# Nodemailer verification using jwt

Tags: node.js, jwt, nodemailer

I'm trying to make e-mail verification using nodemailer and jwt key. The problem is that when I'm trying to verify jwt key, id of user is always undefined.
What am I doing wrong?

```
app.post("/api/createAccount", async (req, res) => {
  const { login, password } = req.body;
  const newUser = await user.create({
    login: login,
    password: password,
  });

  jwt.sign(
    { userId: newUser.id },
    "SECRETKEY",
    {
      expiresIn: "7d",
    },
    (err, token) => {
      const url = `http://localhost:5000/api/confirmMail/${token}`;
      const options = {
        from: "xxx",
        to: login,
        subject: "verifyacc",
        html: `<a href="${url}">${url}</a> `,
      };
      transporter.sendMail(options, function (err, info) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(info);
        }
      });
    }
  );
});

app.get("/api/confirmMail/:token", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
      userId: { id },
    } = jwt.verify(req.params.token, "SECRETKEY");
    await user.update({ confirmed: 1 }, { where: { id: id } });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  return res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/login");
});
```

The error :
err: Error: WHERE parameter "id" has invalid "undefined" value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload of the token you are creating is

```
{ 
  userId: "foobar"
}
```

But in the deconstruction during verification

```
const { userId: { id } } = jwt.verify(...);
```

you expect it to be

```
{
  userId: { 
    id: "foobar"
  }
}
```

because the deconstruction you used, roughly translates to

```
const tmp = jwt.verify(...);
const id = tmp.userId.id;
```

Thus `id` is of course undefined, as `tmp.userId` is (probably) a string or a number, which doesn't have an `id` property.

Use

```
const { userId: id} = jwt.verify(...);
await user.update({ confirmed: 1 }, { where: { id } });
```

which roughly translates to

```
const tmp = jwt.verify(...);
const id = tmp.userId;
```

or alternatively

```
const { userId} = jwt.verify(...);
await user.update({ confirmed: 1 }, { where: { id: userId } });
```